# issue with a fragment application

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to develop an application using fragments that has two different layouts, similar to this one:

[image]

[image]

when i run my app on the phone it crashes immediatly.. here are my codes:

/layout
 
 activity_titles_fragment.xml 
 details_fragment.xml 
 
/layout-land 
activity_titles_fragment.xml 
/sec 
DetailsActivity.java 
 DetailsFragment.java 
 TitlesFragment.java

activity_titles_fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".TitlesFragment" >

<fragment
    class="com.example.fragmentsapp.TitlesFragment"
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

details_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and for landscape, activity_titles_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    class="com.example.fragmentsapp.TitlesFragment"
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DetailsActivity.java

```
package com.example.fragmentsapp;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class DetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
            == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // If the screen is now in landscape mode, we can show the
        // dialog in-line so we don't need this activity.
        finish();
        return;
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
        DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();
        details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
                R.id.details, details).commit();
    }
}

}
```

DetailsFragment.java

```
package com.example.fragmentsapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

public  static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index)
{
    // supply input index as argument
    DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;

}

public int getShownIndex()
{
    return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(container == null)
        return null;

    TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
    text.setText("Fragment number: " + getShownIndex());

    return text;
}

}
```

TitlesFragment.java

```
package com.example.fragmentsapp;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {

boolean mDualPane;
int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // populate list items with list view
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles)));

    // check for mobile dual pane
    View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
    mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice",0);
    }

    if (mDualPane)
    {
        showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
    } 

}



@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    showDetails(position);
}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}



private void showDetails(int index) {
    mCurCheckPosition = index;

    if(mDualPane)
    {

        DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);

        if(details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index)
        {
            details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", index);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: In one area you're using the support library `FragmentActivity` and then using the 4.0 Fragment elsewhere (instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`). Your code seems inconsistent on using support library vs not using it. Also, you didn't post what exception you're getting when crashing, so really, anything could be at fault here.

Comment: im applying this tutorial http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

Comment: could you add error's stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared all of your activities in your Android ? Have you not forgotten this one ?

```
<activity android:name=".activities.FragmentLayout$DetailsActivity">
</activity>
```

Also, you should add a stacktrace each time you are facing such kind of errors.